# child rows as an Object to iterate in datatables jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable that needs to have child rows as in this example https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/abkbg9nx/

what i am troubling with is how to populate the child row with an object and iterate over the object for multiple rows. can some one please help me?
thank you.

```
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        'ajax': 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/16lp6',
        'columns': [
            {
                'className':      'details-control',
                'orderable':      false,
                'data':           null,
                'defaultContent': ''
            },
            { 'data': 'name' },
            { 'data': 'position' },
            { 'data': 'office' },
            { 'data': 'salary' }
        ],
        'order': [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if(row.child.isShown()){
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });

    // Handle click on "Expand All" button
    $('#btn-show-all-children').on('click', function(){
        // Enumerate all rows
        table.rows().every(function(){
            // If row has details collapsed
            if(!this.child.isShown()){
                // Open this row
                this.child(format(this.data())).show();
                $(this.node()).addClass('shown');
            }
        });
    });

    // Handle click on "Collapse All" button
    $('#btn-hide-all-children').on('click', function(){
        // Enumerate all rows
        table.rows().every(function(){
            // If row has details expanded
            if(this.child.isShown()){
                // Collapse row details
                this.child.hide();
                $(this.node()).removeClass('shown');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

instead of having mutiple rows with different attibutes in each i want them in columns and want to have multiple rows of same object

Comment: I'm not really understanding you. The format function returns a HTML table. You can create whatever rows and columns you like.